# class has no 'objects' member

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models

so im new in django and im trying to make a small market. i made a product app. this is the inside codes:
this is for views.py:

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from products.models import product


def index(request):
  Products = product.objects.all()
  return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': Products})

def new(request):
  return HttpResponse('New Product')
```

this is for models.py:

```py
from django.db import models


class product(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  price = models.FloatField()
  stock = models.IntegerField()
  image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2083)
```

i also made a template folder and put this in it for experiment:

```
<h1>Products</h1>
<ul>
  {% for product in Products %}
    <li>{{ product.name }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

and some other usual codes. but i get a pylint error for this part:

```py
product.objects.all()
```

please help me! thanks

Comment: Since you have `return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': Products})`, it should be `{% for product in products %}` in the template. In Python, you usually use `class Product(models.Model):`, and then `products = Product.objects.all()`. If you do this, your code will be more readable for other Python programmers.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try with this
Use pylint --generated-members=objects

Install Django pylint:

`pip install pylint-django`

ctrl+shift+p > Preferences: Configure Language Specific Settings > Python

The settings.json available for python language should look like the below:

```
{
    "python.linting.pylintArgs": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
    ],

    "[python]": {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because `PyLint` doesn't know anything about Django metaclasses which provide `objects` attribute. Anyway your [E1101 error](http://pylint-messages.wikidot.com/messages:e1101) is just a warning and you can disable it or use special [pylint-django](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint-django) plugin to make PyLint aware of magic that Django does.

Another problem of your code is an incorrect usage of context passed to the [render](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) call:

```py
return render(request, 'index.html', {'products': Products})
```

Context is a python [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) object in which `value` will be accessible in the template via `key`. You are passing your queryset via `products` key, but iterate over `Products` (mind the first capital letter) key in your template which is not set so your template will not render anything.

Answer (score 1):

#### Those who are getting errors after adding into the settings.json file add

```
enter code here
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins=pylint_django",
    "--errors-only" 
],
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another option: ~/.pylintrc and edit the line which says:

```
load-plugins=
```

and add django plugin in there:

```
load-plugins=pylint_django
```

which of course needs to be installed first:

```
python3 -m pip install pylint_django
```

Comment: There is no pylint_django egg. There is pylint-django. So it should be pip install pylint-django. https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/

Answer (score 0):

Working off of PRABHAT SINGH RAJPUT's answer I had to do this:

1. Add the following to VSCode's settings.json:

```json
"pylint.args": [
        "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
    ],
```

2. Add the following to my .vscode folder settings.json for the working environment:

```json
    "pylint.args": [
        "--django-settings-module=<yourprojecthere>.settings",
    ]
```

Without the addition of setting the `django-settings-module` I was getting a pylint error `Django was not configured.`

Note: be sure to replace `<yourprojecthere>` with the name of your django project.

Information on configuration found [in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761250/pylint-django-raising-error-about-django-not-being-configured-when-thats-not-th).