# No module named W0614 pylint (fatal)

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm working on a Django project and this error keeps coming up on the first line of every file I work on. I recently reset my computer and this is my first time using VSCode after.

Please, what should I do?

Comment: maybe you need to [enable linting in VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/linting#_enable-linters)?

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed my Linting settings on VSCode. I opened the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P) and selected the Python: Select Linter command. I clicked on Pylint. I had multiple linters enabled before but this replaced them all with Pylint and it worked.

I also followed the steps below.

[Pylint-django raising error about Django not being configured when that's not the case (VSCode)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65761250/pylint-django-raising-error-about-django-not-being-configured-when-thats-not-th)