# Pylint giving false errors on Django project

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, pylint

I'm using VSCode and the Pylint that ships with it, i.e., no extension.
Everything has been running smooth for many months and I've never had an issue with Pylint presenting weird alerts.

I recently started learning Django and today when following the official [Django Documentation tutorial part 4](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/intro/tutorial04/) pylint could not recognize a couple of statements related to a model.

```py
selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,)))
```

**The errors I get from pylint are below**

```
choice_set: Unknown
Cannot access member "choice_set" for type "Question"
  Member "choice_set" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues

and

id: Unknown
Cannot access member "id" for type "Question"
  Member "id" is unknownPylancereportGeneralTypeIssues
```

At first I thought the issue might've been I'd forgot to cross reference the Question and Choice models, but this is not the case. For reference, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEvWB.png) are the related files for the project

I can run the project without errors.

To momentarily solve this problem I just told pylint to ignore this, but I don't fell this best practice. Maybe I'm missing something here?

below the code I ended up writing for these two lines. Any hints?

```py
#(...)
selected_choice = question.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice']) #type: ignore
#(...)
return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('polls:results', args=(question.id,))) #type: ignore
```

**Solution in trial:**

1. pylint-django

- installed via pip (on the virtual environment)
- added parameters to the settings.json file as per below
  [image: settings.json]

nothing changed.

Comment: Did you use the pylint django plugin ? https://pypi.org/project/pylint-django/

Comment: @Pierre.Sassoulas thanks for the info. I installed the package via pip, but I don't seem to be able to make it work on vs-code.
Did I need to fiddle with the .vscode>settings.json, or launch.json if so what are the settings?

Comment: Can [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65834863/18359438) solve your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command `pip install pylint-django` to install pylint-django

and add the following codes to your `settings.json`:

```
"python.linting.pylintArgs": [
    "--load-plugins=pylint_django"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Pierre,  pylint-django addresses these issues.

If you're using vs-code you'll not find an extension on the marketplace. This means you will need to install pylint via pip. Vs-code will not recognize the package, so you will need to add some configurations and fiddle with your workspace or user's settings.json

The article
[PyLint for Django in VSCode](https://dkolodzey.medium.com/pylint-for-django-in-vscode-f3fadb8462d) helped too